# Pop to specific view controller after pushing and presenting few UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I'm making app where there is case that from user can pushing few controllers as well presenting few controllers. But after specific action on last i wanted to pop to that controller from where user get started.

For Example,
From VC1 user push to VC2, again push to VC3. Now, User present to VC4 and then again present to VC5. Now, from VC5 i want to pop to VC1.
This is for example. In between user can push and present number of controllers.

I already tried with followings:

```
 1. [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 2. [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 3. [self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Bu none of this way helps me. Please suggest me for the better solution.

Comment: have you tried -> popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: @Garry : Thanks for ur reply but i don't need to navigate to root. In my above example VC1 is not root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array of ViewControllers pushed on NavigationController.

```
NSArray *arrayViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

/* Content of Array will be @[VC1,VC2,VC3,VC4,VC5.....]
   Now Alter the Array by converting it to Mutable some what like this
   @[VC1,VC2,VC5]
*/
```

Then assign the new array to viewControllers property of navigationController.

```
[self.navigationController viewControllers] = //New Altered Array.
```

Let me know if it helps.

Rgds,
Amit

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. If i go with ur suggested answer. It will remove other controllers from memory? Although i will surely try this one.

Comment: yes .. If you want the view controllers in Memory just shuffle the Order as u want... :-)

Comment: No, after popping to specific view controller i dont want that between controller stay in the memory. So, i'm worrying about it.

Comment: okay.. Then you can go ahead with removing the VC from Array, But I am afraid that [self.navigationController viewControllers] will not give the viewControllers which is presented instead of pushed.

Answer (score 0):

A different and probably safer approach:

```
   for (UIViewController *controller in  self.navigationController.viewControllers) 

   {

         //Do not forget to import YourViewController.h

        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) { 

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                  animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I think it is only works for all pushed view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

just use this code...

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]])
    {


        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I think it is only works for all pushed view controllers.

Comment: @MehulS no it's working ..if ([controller isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]]) when get your class then this condition  is true ....then navigate to your view controller...otherwise loop running..

Answer (score 0):

Try THis

```
[self.nav dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]])
    {

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}

}
];
```